# Unable to work with latest version of wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have downloaded the latest version of wordpress but there is `jQuery conflict` in my `wp-admin`.

I am unable to use `drag and drop` feature of `widgets` and `sliders` of Menu

How can I resolve this problem ?

If it's not possible, then how can  I revert back to previous version ?

`Wordpress 3.8` with `welcome Inn` theme

Answer (score 1):

Just use **"[Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/)"** Plugin from WordPress directory.

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/
```

Hope It solve your problem.